# Tracking focus changes

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I'm trying to track the window focus changes (what application is in the foreground) with python 3.7 in a windows 10 (64b) machine because I'd like to log how much time I spend using each application (I hope chrome is a different app for each tab XD)

I tried to search in the web about how to do it but didn't find it (odd). For now I learnt that I have to install win32api (pypiwin32) and that with this code I can get the name of the window

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
print(GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()))
```

That works fine but I don't want to make a loop with that every second, I'd like to have a callback that when the event 'onWindowFocusChange' or something like that is called run that.

EDIT: As David Heffeman pointed out, I was using wrong terminology. What I meant is the piece of software that I'm interacting with at each point. (None if the screen is blocked, If I'm playing a game and listening to music, the game, if I'm reading a web or a pdf that browser or reader, etc... hope this clarifies the matter.

Comment: Different tabs are not different windows but the caption will most likely change.

Comment: Thanks dude, I just need to find a way now to be notified when the focus change happens. Hope somebody can shed some light.

Comment: Focus and foreground application are not the same thing. You'll need to get a clearer understanding of how Windows works and what the terminology is. It's possible that a CBT hook would need your needs, but I can't tell for sure. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look to see if that can work. Yeah, I'm probably wrong about the terminology. The thing I meant for focus is the piece of software that I'm interacting with. If I'm playing a game but listening music in the foreground is the game for example. Hopes that clarifies

Answer (score 0):

This example code here logs all focus changes: https://gist.github.com/keturn/6695625

Comment: zeroalpha, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)